# Retina image using CSS3 and JavaScript for iphone 5

Tags: javascript, css

I've all image size standard with 288W x 345H. For Retina 576W x 690H.

I'm using CSS3 and JavaScript (Cordova2.1/ Phonegap) for iphone 5 app.

I've tried this for CSS3 retina and it doesn't work

```
    background-size: 288px auto;
```

HTML:

```
  <div id='slider' class='swipe'>
<ul>
<li style='display:block'><div><img style="vertical-align: bottom" src="images/1a.png" border="0" ></div></li>
<li style='display:block'><div><img style="vertical-align: bottom" src="images/1b.png" border="0" ></div></li>
<li style='display:block'><div><img style="vertical-align: bottom" src="images/1c.png" border="0" ></div></li>
<li style='display:block'><div><img style="vertical-align: bottom" src="images/1d.png" border="0" ></div></li>
<li style='display:block'><div><img style="vertical-align: bottom" src="images/1e.png" border="0" ></div></li>
<!-- <li style='display:none'><div><img style="vertical-align: bottom" alt="" title="" border="0" class="shadow" /></div></li> -->
</ul>
```

Comment: So do you want the background images to be sized in half or those images inside img tags?

Comment: The images will be used in swipe feature. I've images as retina 1a@2x.png (retina) and 1a.png (standard). I'll be using CSS3 and JavaScript. Ideally I'd like to use most retina to keep a workload in half.

Comment: Just realised that background-size may not be correct. I'm not sure how to approach a retina image for swipe.

Answer (score 0):

Background-size apply to a background.
http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css3-background-20020802/#background-size

Here you insert your images with the `<img>` tag so background-size won't resolve your problem.

**You have 2 solutions:**
Firstly you **change your DOM and add images with background CSS**, you will solve the problem with this :

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
   only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
   only screen and (min-resolution: 240dpi) {
  [class*="pictos-"] {
    background-image: url("1a-big.png");
    -moz-background-size: 288px 345px;
    -o-background-size: 288px 345px;
    -webkit-background-size: 288px 345px;
    background-size: 288px 345px;
  }
```

}

**Pros for CSS3 solution:**
Retina images will load only on retina and devices higher than 72dpi.

**Cons for CSS3 solution:**
If you have a CMS back-end it's not scalable
This is not that good for accessibility & semantic

**Or export your images for retina with the same resolution (288x345) but with 150 DPI**. The file will be bigger but it should work.

**Pros for DPI solution:**
You have only one image to manage & it's easy to use with a CMS

**Cons for DPI solution:**
Your files are bigger to load and this only affect higher devices than 72dpi

Anyway there is javascript solutions for this problem.

Good luck